# pyramid - modify the session flash

Tags: python, session, pyramid

Pyramid's session.pop_flash() returns a list containing all elements which have been added to the flash queue (not sure if there's a practical limit, but I haven't seen one). I believe this is directly based on php's flash queue.

How do I modify the flash queue directly? Say, for example, that there are 3 elements in it, and I wish to remove one of them (and know exactly which one)?

Currently I'm doing it this way:-

```
q = request.session.pop_flash()
q.pop(index_that_I_want_removed)
for element in q:
    request.session.flash(q)
```

Simple, but seems hackish. Is there a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 0):

The `flash` messages are designed as an opaque queue. This means first-in-first-out. You can only modify the messages inside of it directly if you know the implementation details of the specific queue being used. For example in Pyramid's `SignedCookieSessionFactory` the queue is stored in a specific key in the session and you could overwrite it. However there is no general solution that will work for arbitrary ISession implementations.

**update**

Ok... I think I need to rescind my answer after reviewing with the docs. If you want to ignore a specific flash message then you need to do it in the way you're already doing it. @oluwafemi-sule's answer is not accurate because it is focusing on the session key/values instead of the flash queues stored in the session. The `pop_flash` returns a list which you can iterate however you wish.

Comment: This seems to contradict the answer by @oluwafemi-sule though. And FIFO is fine if I could (for example) have a request.session.pop_one_flash() or similar conceptual function.

Comment: I will update my answer - it's not correct - I should not have answered from memory here.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Yeah I figured the other answer didn't make sense as it did not reference the flash. Seems like there's no other option than the way I've been doing it....